# Returning Values From Methods

Tags: java, class, methods, system.out

How do I print out values for points a-f with out getting it to reiterate what was entered every time? And what am I doing wrong that my program returns that the equation has no solution every time as well?

```
public class LinearEquations {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private double a, b, c, d, e, f = 0;
double x, y;

public double getA() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of a: ");
    double a = input.nextDouble();
    return a;
}

public double getB() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of b: ");
    double b = input.nextDouble();
    return b;
}

public double getC() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of c: ");
    double c = input.nextDouble();
    return c;
}

public double getD() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of d: ");
    double d = input.nextDouble();
    return d;
}

public double getE() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of e: ");
    double e = input.nextDouble();
    return e;
}

public double getF() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of f: ");
    double f = input.nextDouble();
    return f;
}

public boolean isSolvable() { 
    if ((a * d) - (b * c) == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public double getX() {
    double x = (((e * d) - (b * f)) / ((a * d) - (b * c)));
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    double y = (((a * f) - (e * c)) / ((a * d) - (b * c)));
    return y;
}
```

And this is the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinearEquations pointA = new LinearEquations();
    LinearEquations pointB = new LinearEquations();
    LinearEquations pointC = new LinearEquations();
    LinearEquations pointD = new LinearEquations();
    LinearEquations pointE = new LinearEquations();
    LinearEquations pointF = new LinearEquations();

    System.out.println(pointA.getA());
    System.out.println(pointB.getB());
    System.out.println(pointC.getC());
    System.out.println(pointD.getD());
    System.out.println(pointE.getE());
    System.out.println(pointF.getF());

    LinearEquations pointX = new LinearEquations();
    LinearEquations pointY = new LinearEquations();

    if (pointX.isSolvable() && pointY.isSolvable()) {
        System.out.println("x is " + pointX.getX() +
                " and y is " + pointY.getY());
    } else {
        System.out.println("The equation has no solution");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let me try to put in order everything that was mentioned here.

Your first main problem is that you expect your variables to behave in a certain way, but you're not handling them correctly. That is because you are not using their scope correctly.

A scope of a variable is, simply put, where it is available and how long it will "live". For example, the scope of your variables `a, b, c, d, e, f` is the entire class `LinearEquaions`. It means that all these variables should be available to all the member functions of the class, and will live as long as the object containing them exists. Anything outside that object should not have *direct* access to these variables. Once an object dies, it kills all its private variables.

Each time you write code within curly brackets `{}` you define a *new scope*. It is also called 'code blocks'. An important rule to remember when dealing with scopes and curly brackets is that each nested scope (in most cases) have access to the variables and functions that are defined within its containing object. That is why all the functions of a class, which are basically code written within the class' `{}`, can access the private variables of its containing class. Further more, the code that defines each function is, guess what? within the function's `{}`, and so each function has a scope of its own.

This still doesn't directly explain why *your* code doesn't work. Let's take a look at one of your functions. I included the class and variables declaration for the purpose of demonstrating the scope:

```
public class LinearEquations {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private double a, b, c, d, e, f = 0;
    double x, y;

    public double getA() {
        System.out.println("Enter the value of a: ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        return a;
    }
.
.
.
}//end of class LinearEquations, and its scope
```

Take a look at the scope of the class, and notice how it contains all the code written in it. Now, notice the code block that defines the function `getA()`. Outside of the function, you define your variables as follows:

```
private double a, b, c, d, e, f = 0;
```

Here, you say: I want all these to be available anywhere inside my class, but only to members of `this` class, they are all of type double, and equal to 0.

Next,

```
public double getA() {
        System.out.println("Enter the value of a: ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        return a;
}
```

the line `double a = input.nextDouble();` defines a *new* variable called `a`, within the scope of the function, which has NOTHING to do with variable `a` of your class. This happens because you can have variables of similar names within different scopes. This is the first issue of your code. You lose values because, instead of doing work and saving it within your class variables, you save it in a temporary variable that will die as soon as the function finish its execution, and return it (which does not equal to saving it, obviously).

To fix that, as mohmicro suggested, you should use the `this` keyword to specify which variable you want the compiler to update. In other words, when using `this.a = input.nextDouble();` instead of `double a = input.nextDouble();`, you are saying: save the work I just did to the class' `a` variable, and not the function's `a` variable. The same process should be applied to all your getB/C...F functions, and will insure that the values you get from the user are stored in the class, which in turn will allow `isSolvable()`, `getX()`, and `getY()` to access variables with actual information (because in your current implementation, `a, b, c, d, e, f` remain 0).

---

To answer your second question, each of your functions achieve more than one task. Generally speaking, this is considered to be bad practice, and results in incohesive functions. While it *might* seems more efficient or using less lines of code, it adds confusion when trying to read the code for purposes of maintenance or debugging. Why? because you might overlook some of the function's purposes when it has more than one, or when it's not a matter of one-function-one-purpose.

It is also the root of your problem. Each time you want to get the value of any one of your variables `a,...,f`, you engage in a dialog with the user, and make him change the value of the variable. This is because your function does two things, it sets a value and returns it. Very undesirable. To solve this, you want to divide and conquer. Each of your get functions should be broken into two different functions. One to set a variable with a value from the user, and another to get that value when needed. Here's an example:

```
public void setA() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of a: ");
    this.a = input.nextDouble();  //get the value from the user and insert it to the object's variable a
}

public double getA() {
    return a;
}
```

This way, whenever you need a new value from the user for variable `a`, you call `setA()`, and whenever you need to get what is in `a`, you call `getA()`. One-function-one-purpose.

Comment: You, sir, have helped me more than my professor has all semester. Much appreciated.

Comment: I know your pain. Happy I could help! Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic has some issues, you are creating **8** LinearEquation objects when you actually just want 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinearEquations theOne = new LinearEquations();

    System.out.println(theOne.getA());
    System.out.println(theOne.getB());
    System.out.println(theOne.getC());
    System.out.println(theOne.getD());
    System.out.println(theOne.getE());
    System.out.println(theOne.getF());


    if (theOne.isSolvable()) {
        System.out.println("x is " + theOne.getX() +
                " and y is " + theOne.getY());
    } else {
        System.out.println("The equation has no solution");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add that for the sake of cohesiveness, you might want to break all your get methods into "setters" and "getters". Meaning, set are all functions that request data from the user, should be void, and only assign values to the local members of the class (i.e. a,b,c,d,e,f), and the get are those who return the values respectively. This way you will not have to engage in dialog with the user or reset the variables each time you need to get a value (hence the cohesiveness)

Answer (score 3):

In your methods you are not writing data to class members. You just redefine a local variable inside the function and write the value to it.
in your code

```
public double getF() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of f: ");
    double f = input.nextDouble();
    return f;
}
```

it should be

```
public double getF() {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of f: ");
    this.f = input.nextDouble();
    return f;
}
```

This is beside you youse many objects each had one input value. you should use only one that has all the values so that the equation claclulation works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I tried your suggestion and nothing changed. I don't understand what exactly I should do after reading your bottom sentence. Thanks for the help, regardless.

Comment: Simply put, you are not handling your variables carefully enough, and you are losing data because of scope. You should read about scope and code blocks, two _very_ important and basic concepts of coding.